# Laravel : How to get count for eloquent relation

Tags: laravel

I have defined my relations in my models :

```
public function orders() {
    return $this->hasMany(Orders::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

How to get user with order count ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `withCount` for that:

```
$user = User::withCount('orders')->first();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

Comment: It's working. Thank you!